# running into node.js TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer with the simplest possible script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So I ran into an error reading 
`TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer` when running a node.js script, and after a lot of stackoverflow and tutorial googling I couldn't find the solution, so I created sample code literally copy-pasted from the [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp) node.js tutorial, which still returns the TypeError. The code in question is:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  //Open a file on the server and return it's content:
  fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

demofile1.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My Header</h1>
<p>My paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the console still returns the error

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:642:11)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:617:10)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (*file path*)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
```

I'm assuming that something has to be wrong with my environment, but I've installed node.js and run npm install fs manually, all to no avail. I can run other node.js servers fine, but the error comes when I try to read an html file using fs.

Thanks

Comment: Your code hasn't checked if `err` contains an error. I'm guessing you might be running the script from a different directory so `fs.readFile()` checks the wrong location, thus `data` would probably be `undefined`. Also `fs` is an internal module, you should _not_ install it with `npm install fs`, as that installs a 3rd party library which is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that `demofile1.html` is not found on the same path as where you are starting you server.

I would recommend to:

1. Try placing the `server.js` (or whatever you named your js file) in the same path as your `demofile1.html` and try again
2. If you need them on subfolders, try navigating with absolute paths, or use some npm extension like [rootpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rootpath)
3. In the fs callback, try logging data, it is also a good practice to use [existsSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) to be sure that your app doesn't crash

Comment: It is _not_ good practice to use `existsSync()` (see [recommended approaches without `fs.exists[Sync]()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback)) as that creates the potential for race conditions in the filesystem, e.g. you check for existence, returns true, and some other process immediately deletes the file before you read it into a buffer. You should attempt to read the file and handle any errors accordingly.

Comment: I usually use [ReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream); it depends on the usage you need for the file. For this question, I see the user depends on the contents of the file, so verifying that it exists can lead to a separate flow to handle that case (which is out of the scope of the question). Agree that a better error handling is needed though.

Comment: feeling really dumb for asking this question to begin with, apparently node doesn't look at the path the .js file is in when it's in a subfolder, it looks at the path the terminal is currently cd'd into. I was running the js file from a subfolder but wasn't including the subfolder in the path name. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend W3Schools as a respectable tutorial source, and this is a great example why not: they don't teach good habits like error handling. Because you copied and pasted the example as they had it, your error is rather cryptic. However with good error handling, your error would be caught earlier and give you a much better indication of what went wrong.

With that in mind, try this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  //Open a file on the server and return it's content:
  fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err; // crash with actual error instead of assuming success
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```